# How can I combine two frames in column manner in HTML and make it as one scrollable page?

Tags: html, css

```html
<!DOCSTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
   <title>Combine two column frames into one scrollabe page</title>
   <frameset cols="25%,75%" frameborder="0"> 
     <frame src="lframe.html" scrolling="no">
     <frame src="rframe.html">
   </frameset>
  </head>
</html>
```

I want to combine the column frames and make it as single scrollable page.

Comment: Your HTML page doesn't have a `<body>`, so I guess the browser has nothing to show...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sync the scroll bar for 2 iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35238103/how-to-sync-the-scroll-bar-for-2-iframe)